# If you take a level in Warlock, do all your other spell slots suddenly start recharging over a short rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, spell-slots

The [warlock's Pact Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#PactMagic) feature says:

> #### Spell Slots
>
> The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have. The table also shows what the level of those slots is; all of your spell slots are the same level. To cast one of your warlock spells of 1st level or higher, you must expend a spell slot. **You regain all expended spell slots when you finish a short or long rest.**

If you multiclass from another caster class and take a level in Warlock, do all your other spell slots suddenly start recharging over a short rest?

Answer (score -6):

The Dungeons and Dragons games tend to have rules with implied ownership when they explain things within a class. Ive asked a couple of these myself, such as can a [wizard convert his spells to any cure spell with a single level of cleric](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90551/23058).

So in this case, its implied that the recharge should only affect the warlocks spells, even if they dont come right out and say it.

Comment: This is not the right answer.

Comment: They do come out and say Warlock spellslots and other spellslots are different, and recover based on their individual rules (Warlock at shortrest, Everyone else at longrest)

Comment: Can you support any of this with evidence? I feel like you have the right start here but you don't go into nearly enough detail or provide any kind of support for your logic.

Comment: The only support I am able to offer is how they have written the rules across editions. Since the rules for a class are defined within that class instead of class features being described and then classes state which abilities they use. This moves us towards the expectation that the rules are meant for that class, or else it would redirect us like when they say it works like a feature from so and so class.