# How does the Mystic Theurge's Combined Spells feature work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing

Some time ago I had asked [a question about how some special abilities of classes interacted with other classes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90551/23058), and recently updated the [accepted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147360/23058) due to a linked [FAQ](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r93s?New-FAQ-Spontaneous-Casting-and-Multiple-Classes).

I find myself having to get further clarification on this. The FAQ mentions that an ability such as Combined Spells will allow these interactions to exist. I plan on playing a cleric/wizard/mystic theurge spellcaster who specializes in raising the dead, so a necromancer. One of the Oracle revelations under Juju called Spirit Vessels increases the amount of undead you can control per CL by 2 - which, when combined with MT, is sweet. However, I do not plan on being an Oracle/Wizard, but would be happy to just level-dip for the ability.

Does the MT's Combined Spells ability work on a class which it is not leveling up? That is, if I have MT progressing cleric and wizard, would I benefit from the oracle ability to those two classes?

Normally, the oracle's SVR (Spirit Vessels revelation) will only apply to the oracle class. From the FAQ that was linked to the ability, Combined Spells changes this. Now if oracle was being increased as part of MT, I am confident that SVR would apply to oracle and wizard (being the other side of MT in this case). What I am asking about is when oracle is not one of the active aspects of the MT progression. As cleric and wizard are being increased, but does the Combined Spells feature also allow the oracle's ability to also affect the cleric and wizard levels?

Edit: So I figured out why I didnt seem to be on the same page as everyone else. I was still thinking in terms of abilities whereas the FAQ specifically called out the abilities I had originally asked about. So when I opened this one, I was still thinking of the spell conversation as an ability that was being allowed, instead of the wording that MT was using.

Comment: Could this question be stated more plainly? I think it's *Does the supernatural ability spirit vessels apply to all of a multiclass oracle's casting classes or only to a multiclass oracle's oracle casting?* but I can't be sure. (It sounds like you want to ask a broader question about this kind of thing generally, but I don't think that's wise: without a second or third similar example, I'm not sure a satisfactory answer would be forthcoming. Folks would be forced to guess what you mean by an ability similar to this example.)

Comment: Rather than simply adding a rewording of your question at the end of the question, you should edit the question as a whole to read as if it were always the best, clearest version of itself.

Comment: @V2Blast I prefer the adding so that people can see my multiple thought processes as I tried to ask

Comment: Anyone interested in an older version of the question can see the revision history. Seeing your "multiple thought processes" likely makes it less clear to people what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your final question doesn't seem to be directly related to the body, so I'll answer the body first:

The Spirit Vessels ability references the spell *[animate dead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead/)* which is available to all 3 classes. RAW, this means that any version of *animate dead* you use would benefit from the [Revelation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/#TOC-Revelation) because none of the Revelation class feature, the Revelation itself, nor the *animate dead* spell contradict it's "pool" not being removed from the class that cast it individually.

---

Notably, [it is unclear which CL you use to determine your total](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2u704?Animate-Dead-from-multiple-classes) (as a GM, I would say it's simply your highest capable of casting the spell and be done with it)... but that doesn't directly affect your question. The multiple-cast cap seems to transcend the class used to activate the ability.

---

Now to answer your final question,

[Mystic Theurge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge/)'s Spells per Day feature includes that you can dynamically select which classes increase in CL potency by level

> If a character had more than one arcane spellcasting class or more than one divine spellcasting class before he became a mystic theurge, he must decide to which class he adds each level of mystic theurge for the purpose of determining spells per day.

Furthermore, the [Combined Spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge/#TOC-Combined-Spells-Su-) feature does not have any language restricting which spell lists it applies to.

For these reasons, all of your Mystic Theurge abilities would also apply to your Oracle level and spells (ie you could prepare 1st level Oracle spells as 2nd level Wizard spells, or ironically, 2nd level Cleric spells)

*A particularly strict GM could complain about this and the obvious response is to drop one of your M.T. divine spellcasting levels into Oracle; this would make it irrefutably part of M.T. I doubt most GM's would be this cruel, as you are already going *Mystic Theurge* (which is far from optimized) and *dipping Oracle* forcing you to have a Curse that you never decrease the penalty/gain benefits from.